# Length of any of the diagonals of a rhombus of given side and a given angle

Tags: geometry

Suppose, the values of any one of the angles and the side of a rhombus are given. How to find the length of any of the diagonals?

Comment: Given two sides and the included angle, you can use cosine law to find one of the diagonals.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one angle, then you have all of the angles. If you have one side, then you know the length of all of the sides. Choose any right triangle out of the four ones which were born after drawing the diagonals. You know all of the angles of the triangle, and you know one side. Use the cosines and sines and you should have the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Straight Trig:

$$ 2\, a \sin (\alpha/2) ,2\, a \cos (\alpha/2) $$